# Navigation menu with php, js and mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, css

Note: *original* & *new* inside the code.

My issue here is that the *original* "parent" is not very SEO friendly and does not act according to plan, it also does not get fetched up in sitemaps.

However the *new* is SEO friendly, will get picked up in sitemaps and will be according to plan in the end.

I need it to be a link so that you can see both the navigation menu to the left with the name of each menu / sub-menu and in the center of the page have a picture with the name for each sub-menu depending on which parent you click in the navigation menu on the left.

With the *new* line added i get a page refresh due to the link, so the sub-menus only flash open for a second before the refresh.

What i need help solving is:

-Making the sub-menu stay open during page refresh so you can use both the navigation from the sidebar navigation and the center navigation.

Thanks in beforehand!
//Jim

**This is my current menu:**

```
<div id="container">
    <dl>
    <?php 
        $select_category = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE hidden = 0 ORDER BY menu ASC");
            while($ln = mysql_fetch_array($select_category)){
                $idcat = $ln['nmr'];
                $catname = str_replace(' ', '-', $ln['menu']);
    ?>

            *Original*: <dt><a href="#/<?php echo $catname; ?>/" style="color:#000;" ><strong><?php echo $ln['menu']; ?></strong></a></dt>

        *New*: <dt><a href="http://www.mysite.com/cats/<?php echo $msub['nmr'];?>/<?php echo $mname; ?>/" style="color:#000;" ><strong><?php echo $mn['menu']; ?></strong></a></dt>

        <?php 
            $select_sub = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submenu WHERE nmrmenu = '$idcat' AND hidden = 0");
            if(mysql_num_rows($select_sub) == 0){
            }else {
        ?>
        <dd>
        <ul>
        <?php
            while($lsub = mysql_fetch_array($select_sub)){
                $subname = str_replace(' ', '-', $lsub['submenu']);
                $pil = '&raquo;';
                $brnr = $lsub['nmr'];
        ?> 
        <li> <a href="http://www.mysite.com/cat/<?php echo $lsub['nmr'];?>/<?php echo $subname; ?>/" style="color:#333;"> <?php echo $pil; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $lsub['submenu']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        </dd>
       <?php } ?>
      </dl>
     <?php } ?>
   </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container{ margin:auto; margin-left:10px; }
dl, dt, dd, ul, li, a{ margin:0; padding:0; }
a{ text-decoration: none; color:#0F0; }
li{ padding-left:.6em; list-style-type:none; color:#FF0; }
dl{ width:100px; }
dt{  }
```

**JS:**

```
$(function()
{
    $("dd:not(first)").hide();
    $("dt a").click(function()
     {
         $("dd").slideUp("normal");
         $(this).parent("dt").next("dd").slideDown("normal");
     });
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamW0009/eFPpC/1/) of my code.

Comment: Any chance of a jsfiddle with HTML, CSS and JS? :)

Comment: @Technoh here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eFPpC/

The JS doesn't seem to work on it however, but hopefully it makes a little more sense.

Comment: I've fixed your jsFiddle and added it to your question (you forgot to include jQuery). Now, the main difference between your new and old code is that the old code did not trigger a refresh so the navigation could stay open. With your new code, the whole page gets refreshed. The only thing I can think of to keep the navigation open would be to use ajax to swap out the page content.

Comment: @GrahamWalters Thanks mate, much appreciated with the edits. Perhaps you are able to provide some coded answer to what i can do? I've searched about this pretty long, and some people seem to get it to work with different measures than ajax, however on my dynamic menu it doesn't seem to work with their setup.

Comment: Any chance you can link me to an example of what you're trying to do? I must be missing something if they're not using ajax.

Comment: @GrahamWalters Do you have an email?

Comment: I do, but it's best to keep everything on StackOverflow so that others can see and help. You can remove the link from your comment later

Comment: @GrahamWalters Ok, well take this site for example, it has the original setup: http://www.vesundberg.com. What i'm looking for is to make the parents on the side-menu have links instead of hash tags as explained in the coding, so that when you press a parent it will refresh and show each child for that parent as it currently do, but also show the childs as you see the products if you press a child in the menu. So that you may navigate with the sidebar or by pressing images that will appear in the middle of the page when a parent in the side-menu is clicked. Sorry if it sounds confusing! :D

Comment: You would be better off using PHP for this then. In the PHP code, check if the sub-menu matches the currently loaded page and display that sub-menu instead of hiding it. If you give me a few hours I should be able to post an answer with code.

Comment: @Technoh Please take the time you need, just got home from the office, so I wont be able to update the coding untill tomorrow morning. One question though, I've been thinking of making a php version for it, but wont it exclude the childs from the page so the SEO gets worse?

Comment: Quick question, do you have a php variable for the current category number, i.e. for this page `http://www.mysite.com/cats/123/Cars/` do you have something like `$GET['cats']` which = 123. Presuming you're using something like `.htaccess` you should

Comment: @GrahamWalters I'm using htaccess yes, "123" is the category number, so yes $GET['cat'] is what i'm using to list out the products under each child. :) So my plan is to do somewhat the same but for parents to list out childs that then can navigate to the child category of choice.

Comment: @GrahamWalters What i don't get is how i can keep the chosen parent category open and still list its child categories in the side-menu when refreshed to list the pictures in the middle area of the website, while showing the parent categories of the other child categories in the side-bar as well as showing the other parents so you easily can click on another parent to see other child categories in the side-menu and middle area. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll want to clean up your html and css. Then you're going to want to check which page the user is viewing and if it's a category, show that specific sub navigation.

Here's your cleaned up php/html. I think you've messed up your variable names, so if this doesn't work, that's probably why.

Example, you have `*New*: <dt><a href="http://www.mysite.com/cats/<?php echo $msub['nmr'];?>` but `$msub['nmr'];` is not set in the code above where it is used.

```
<ul id="nav-container">
<?php 
$select_category = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE hidden = 0 ORDER BY menu ASC");
while ($ln = mysql_fetch_array($select_category)) {
  $idcat = $ln['nmr'];
  $catname = str_replace(' ', '-', $ln['menu']);

  echo '<li>'
  echo '<a href="http://www.mysite.com/cats/'.$msub['nmr'].'/'.$mname.'/" ><strong>'.$mn['menu'].'</strong></a>';
  echo '<ul';

  // This is where we check which page you're on, and show the sub navigation if it corresponds to that page.
  if ($GET['cat'] == $msub['nmr'])
    echo ' style="display:block;">';
  else
    echo '>';


  while ($lsub = mysql_fetch_array($select_sub)) {
    $subname = str_replace(' ', '-', $lsub['submenu']);
    $pil = '&raquo;';
    $brnr = $lsub['nmr'];

    echo '<li><a href="http://www.mysite.com/cat/'.$lsub['nmr'].'/'.$subname.'/">'.$pil.'&nbsp;'.$lsub['submenu'].'</a></li>';
  }

  echo '</ul>';
  echo '</li>';
}

?>

</ul>
```

Here's the CSS to go with it.

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}
li {
    padding-left: .6em;
    list-style-type:none;
    color:#FF0;
}

#nav-container li ul {
    display: none; /* Hide all sub navigations to start with */
}
```

Because of the way I used css, you no longer need to use JavaScript :)

Comment: But you still need to show sub-menus when clicking on the parent category, so won't you still need javascript for that?

Comment: While the page is being built, the php will insert `style="display:block;"` on whichever sub nav is to be displayed. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamW0009/eFPpC/2/) of what the output should look like. The jsFiddle is an example of what would be shown when you navigate to `http://www.mysite.com/cats/123/Cars/`

Comment: In your jsfiddle if you click on Guns you are taken to the page instead of the sub-menu sliding down and the Cars sub-menu sliding up. Jim will correct me if I'm wrong but I think that is the expected behavior he is looking for.

Comment: I will give this a try, i think it looks like it's the way i want it to be in the fiddle. @Technoh feel free to give a answer as well, i will try all answers i get when i get to the office tomorrow morning.

Comment: Having the sub nav slid down and then refresh the page is not exactly the best user experience. I got rid of the javascript for that reason. If he wanted the navigation to animate like that, then I would go back to my ajax recommendation because the entire page would not have to refresh.

Comment: @GrahamWalters You're right about the variable not being set for * new *, it was only shown as an example of how it could've looked when finished. As i wrote in the previous comment i will try it out tomorrow morning :) One question: with this all parents will be listed even if a parent is clicked on?

Comment: Yes, just like the example jsfiddle. As for the variables, if you don't get it to work, just update your question with the new code and I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I would have written, I see no point in copy-pasting a new one. However I'm curious as to why you have removed the sliding when on a page. The sliding should continue working even when on a given product page and in the jsfiddle it doesn't slide.

Comment: @GrahamWalters Great, just wanted to ask to be sure, i will post an update tomorrow on how it went! Thanks!

Comment: @Technoh The sliding is removed since the JS is removed, to keep the sliding effect new JS can be added i think. ^^

Comment: @JimSundqvist Yes, I thought you wanted to keep the sliding, hence my question :) If the sliding is not important then what Graham proposed seems like the perfect answer.

Comment: @Technoh The sliding is not necessary, but i might add it in one day :)

Comment: @GrahamWalters I've tested it out, had to do a few changes to make it work as it should. Now design-wise I would like to change the sub-menus little, not entirely sure how to make it possible though ^^' I know it's with CSS but I've forgotten the command. I want the sub-menus appear slightly indented beneath the parent menu, now as you can see on the fiddle the sub-menu appear far to the right, i want it more to the left, like you saw on the website the other day :)

Comment: @GrahamWalters I solved the positioning of the sub-menus as well!